# Show images in table cells

Tags: javascript, image

I would like to create a 13 x 4 table and insert an image called back.gif into each cell.  It's not working.

There is an error with the line 'td1.appendChild(backImg);' but I can't figure it out.

My code looks like this:

```
<script>

var preLoadImages = new Array('<img src=\"0.png\">','<img src=\"1.png\">','<img src=\"2.png\">','<img src=\"3.png\">');
var cardSet = new Array (0,1,2,3,4);

var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
    for (var j = 0; j<13; j++){
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        var backImg = document.getElementById("imageBack");
        //backImg.src = "back.gif";

    td1.appendChild(backImg);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    table.appendChild(tr);
    }
}
document.body.appendChild(table);

    </script>

    <img id="imageBack" src="back.gif" height="90" />

</body>
```

Comment: Try to move your script below the img tag. You're trying to reference the element before its creation. Also, appendChild will move your img to each cell instead of copying it. You need to create a new image for each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var preLoadImages = new Array('<img src=\"0.png\">','<img src=\"1.png\">','<img src=\"2.png\">','<img src=\"3.png\">');
    var cardSet = new Array (0,1,2,3,4);

    var table = document.createElement('table');
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
        for (var j = 0; j<13; j++){
            var td1 = document.createElement('td');
            //create here your img element and set the src
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src", "back.gif");
            td1.appendChild(img);
            tr.appendChild(td1);
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(table);
});
```

Comment: thanks so much cralfaro. Just curious, do you know how I can add the images in the preLoadImages array into the table after a user action (such as button click?)

Comment: You can load an array with a list of images paths and for each position, create an image with that src and add to the td-tr. And trigger everything when the user click on some button. Should work

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going wrong:

- `document.getElementById` will return `null` because the `<img>` isn't yet constructed by the time your code is executed.
- You're not cloning the image but reusing it
- If you were to clone the image, you would need to create a new `id` for each image instance.

You could try to create the `<img>` in code by using `document.createElement("img")`.

```
var createBackImg = function() {
  var newImg = document.createElement("img");
  newImg.src = "back.gif";
  newImg.height = 90;
  return newImg;
}
```

Then, you can use `append` to add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```
<head>
  <script>
function myFunction(){
  var preLoadImages = new Array('<img src=\"0.png\">','<img src=\"1.png\">','<img src=\"2.png\">','<img src=\"3.png\">');
  var cardSet = new Array (0,1,2,3,4);
  var table = document.createElement('table');

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
    for (var j = 0; j<13; j++){
      var td1 = document.createElement('td');
      var backImg = document.createElement("img");
      backImg.src = "images/back.gif";
      td1.appendChild(backImg);
      tr.appendChild(td1);
      table.appendChild(tr);
    }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(table);
  alert("myFunc");
}
  </script>

</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">


</body>
```